# Object with curves sliding when animating

Tags: animation, modifiers, objects, snapping, curve-modifier

i am trying to animated a object with a lot of separate parts including objects that is linked up with curves.

at first the animation looks good, but when the object moves the object linked to the curve is sliding.

i have tried to apply the curve modifier to the object, but when I do the object just straights out.

here is a video describing the problem:
https://youtu.be/UW15utlcF4w

i want the object to stay solid when animating, I have tried joining the objects but with no luck.
is there a way to apply the curve to the object? that should solve the problem.

thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Maybe parent both the object and the curve to the main shoe object? Or apply the Curve modifier? You can share your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I tried applying and parenting, but none of them worked. can´t upload more than 30 MB to the link you sendt. This we-transfer link should work instead: https://we.tl/t-v0exMFPnwM

Comment: i figured it out. I just had to apply all the modifiers from top to bottom and apply the curve modifier as the last modifier.